# Message not showing when using javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Not sure why the message (msg in PHP) isn't showing. When user inputs email and clicks button a message should appear however nothing happens. Bit unsure.

HTML:

```html
   <div class="fp-form">
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<button class="btn reset-btn" type="submit" name="button">Reset Password</button>
<br><br>
<p id="response"></p>
   </div>
```

PHP:

```html
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  global $conn;

  $email = $conn->real_string_escape($_POST['email']);

  $sql = $conn->query("SELECT u_id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
  if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
      exit(json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox')));
  } else
      exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Please check your inputs')));
}
```

JS:

```html
var email = $("#email");

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.reset-btn').on('click', function () {
    if (email.val() !="") {
      email.css('border', '2px solid green');

      $.ajax({
        url: 'forgottenPassword.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          email: email.val()
        }, success: function(response) {
            if (!response.success)
              $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "red");
            else
              $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "green");
        }
      });
    } else
      email.css('border', '2px solid red');
  });
});
```

Will add any more info if needed, thanks

Comment: Have you checked if a POST request with the email is done correctly?

Comment: In order to identify the problem start with: Instead of '$("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "red");' and 'green', use "console.debug(response);" to diagnose if you get any response.

Comment: Nothing shows in the console when I click the button, I have tried "console.debug(response);"

Comment: You need to put the var email = $("#email"); in the function. It's currently outside the function and is set to blank when the document is ready

Comment: @Seb POST request is working fine

Comment: @JasonK that was the problem, thanks